# woocommerce smart coupons disable credit details "gift coupons to someone else"

Tags: woocommerce

I would like to disable the option to gift coupons to someone else. Is there a way to hide this? 
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QV5j.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this short article on how to disable or hide the coupons in WooCommerce plugin: https://www.skyverge.com/blog/hide-woocommerce-coupon-fields
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That wasn't the question that I had. I want to be able to use coupons that are generated automatically. I just don't want the buyer to be able to forward the coupon to another user through WooCommerce.

Comment: Maybe this plugin will help, it should prevent multiple uses of the single coupon code https://gist.github.com/MWDelaney/0200a347e552350398ee4fe4cc7a10ce